# Set full path to output directory for generated code using swagger and gradle

Tags: java, gradle, swagger

Im using the [Gradle Swagger Generator Plugin](https://github.com/int128/gradle-swagger-generator-plugin) plugin to generate models from yaml files.

Im using the generateSwaggerCode command. Instead of generating the models in the build directory, I want them generated in `src/gen/java/com/cb/models`

In build.gradle I have:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.hidetake.swagger.generator' version '2.13.0'
}

dependencies {
    swaggerCodegen 'io.swagger:swagger-codegen-cli:2.3.1'
}

swaggerSources {
    petstore {
        inputFile = file('petstore.yaml')
        code {
            language = 'java'
            components = ['models']
            configFile = file('config.json')
            outputDir = file('src/gen/java/')
        }
    }
}
```

And config.json is:

```
{
  "dateLibrary": "java8",
  "hideGenerationTimestamp": true,
  "modelPackage": "com.cb.models"
}
```

I generate the models using the command `./gradlew generateSwaggerCode`

However, the models end up at `src/gen/java/src/main/java/com/cb/Pet.java`

I cannot figure out how to get rid of `src/main/java` in the path. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The **sourceFolder** property can be used to control the location that the source code is written to underneath the **outputDir**

This is accessible as an **additionalProperty** or in your example you could place it in the config.json file.

For Example:

```
code {
            language = 'java'
            components = ['models']
            configFile = file('config.json')
            outputDir = file("$projectDir")
            additionalProperties = [sourceFolder: "src/gen/java"]
}
```

Note: I changed the **outputDir** to the project directory to use the **sourceFolder** property to add the "src/gen/java" part.

Alternatively in config.json, and without changing the **outputDir**, we can set **sourceFolder** to blank:

```
{
  "dateLibrary": "java8",
  "hideGenerationTimestamp": true,
  "modelPackage": "com.cb.models"
  "sourceFolder": ""
}
```